# "Hardware shut off" pumps when water leak is detected

Tags: arduino, mosfet, pwm, pulldown, fluid-pump

I did a lot of research but cannot find a clear solution to my problem - maybe that's also because of a lack of understanding proposed solutions, of course. After all I read, I feel confident enough to ask my own question.

I have the following situation:

I have a system using 2 water pumps, which are driven by a PWM signal (GPIO.)  The pumps are connected at con+/con- (see circuit per pump below.)

[image: pump driving circuit]

I would like to add a double protected leak detection - software and hardware wise - hardware wise because in the past I already had an issue with the processor getting stuck while the pump was running.

Here is the circuit and how I want to adapt it:

[image: pump shut-off circuit]

The idea is to pull down the gate voltage of the MOSFETs when water is connecting the probe pads.

In addition I will then measure the voltage at the normally not connected probe pad as I expect to have a HIGH signal there from the then still driven PWM signals.

My questions are:

1. Does this work at all?
2. Will the analog pin detect a voltage as planned?
3. Do I have to add someting? For example a resistor between the gates and the probe? --> At the moment I did not do this on purpose because I thought anything above 220ohm added there will be "ignored" like the 10k pull down resistor.

EDIT: Another solution came to my mind. Instead of trying to pull down the gate, maybe it's a better solution to bypass the pumps like shown below?

Again, there would be the question if something needs to be added!?

EDIT EDIT: I tried this idea and shorting the pumps is really a bad idea, when I look at the burned transistor in front of me :-/

Comment: Water is not a good conductor.  You would need a very large contact area for your probes for the water to be able to "short circuit" the gate signal.

Comment: Of course, you are right with that, but it will not be destilled water - shouldn't normal tap water be conductive enough? I am planning pads on a pcb with 2mm diameter and 3mm distance between each other.

Comment: Even tap water won't conduct that well.  Try it and see before you design and build a circuit around the idea.  All you need is some aluminum foil, a voltmeter, a power supply, and a resistor.

Comment: @JRE Tap water doesn't conduct particularly well at DC (although it will conduct). Water with salts (as is common in tapwater) actually forms a double layer capacitor with an electrode so when the circuit makes (at DC) it acts as a differentiator. Therefore there would be a voltage pulse on the sensing side that would reduce to a lower voltage after a small period of time. The *effective* capacitance can be huge. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-layer_capacitance

Comment: @PeterSmith:  Look at the circuit ideas.  The concept here is to short a signal to ground, or even worse to short the power for the motors around the motor.  I don't see where any of the points you mention will make any difference.  Tap water or salt water with small contacts in a drop of water will **not** get anywhere close to short circuiting a 220 ohm - let alone short circuiting a motor.

Comment: But in theory, as I do not have everything here right now to try it...let's say instead of the probe we have a switch with whom I can close the line. Would the circuit itself be ok?

Comment: If you ground the gate with a switch, then the pump will be off, no matter what the PWM does.

Comment: Using water and electrodes to the gates promises a frustrating experience. Make a water detector that works and produces a reliable signal to drive the gates.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some fail-safe features, then you might want to read up on the concepts of FMEA. With this you can create a spreadsheet and list a number of 'what would happen if?' questions and rate the possibility and the effects.

There a few simple techniques you could implement that would make your system more robust.

1. The basic rule is- tolerate one failure, but be able to detect all.
2. Understand the failure modes of your circuit.
3. Add redundancy to detect and mitigate a failure.

Some suggestions:

You can monitor the current of your pumps, so the micro can determine if they are running or not.

Add a relay in the power feed to the pumps. Use a 'charge-pump' circuit so that the micro has to toggle a GPIO in order for the charge pump to keep the relay activated. This is a form of watchdog.

The micro can measure the voltage to see if the relay is switched on or off.

With a little extra circuitry, your micro can detect the input voltage, whether the watchdog relay is operating, detect if a mosfet has failed, detect if a pump is connected or not and how much current it is drawing (doesn't need to be super accurate).

With some careful design of the microcontroller code, you can have it detect for correct operation or if there is a failure and fail safe.Things like ensuring the code that toggles the charge pump for the relay is separate from the code that kicks the watchdog. That way if the micro gets caught in a loop, worst case it either kicks the watchdog or toggles the charge pump - not both. On failure, the micro should reboot due to the watchdog not being kicked or the relay drops out.

Next trick is water detection. The others have suggested it's not quite a simple as you'd like. Passing a DC current through a conductive liquid causes electrolysis and will cause the wires or pads to be eaten away. You need to apply an AC signal to avoid this. The AC signal can easily be created via the GPIO. There's plenty written about this on the interwebs.

Other techniques is to have a pressure sensor. If a pipe is broken, then the detected water pressure may not be what it should. Your micro can detect this and stop the pumps then raise an alarm. Maybe even a flow sensor might be sensible - my dishwasher has something like this.

Once you have a number of measurements, you can correlate these to determine correct or incorrect operation. Eg you know you are running the pump, you can measure the pump current, water pressure and flow. Conversely if you have stopped the pump, there should be no current, pressure or flow. And so on.

Most of this can be done with resistors, transistors and capacitors. Nothing exotic.

Comment: Excellent answer introducing the concept of safety in electronic systems.